# How to initialize items in a range in a captureless lambda, C++

Tags: c++, lambda

My code is below. This works, It allows me to have exactly one range in my lambda.

So I guess what my question is, is how do I achieve the same results without using

```
"if(LOOP > 2 && LOOP < 5){int THERANGEVALUE = 2; FUNC[THERANGEVALUE]();}"?
```

And instead initialize an item in my captureless lambda as being ranged instead. aka, item_2 being item_range(2,4). And then also being able to continue my lambda normally, whereas Item_3 will equate to item_5.

Thank you for any help in advance, I will gladly add more input if requested.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void (*FUNC[3])(void) = { //captureless lambda.
    /*ITEM_0*/[](){ cout << "x" << endl;},
    /*ITEM_1*/[](){cout << "y" << endl;},
    /*ITEM_2->ITEM_4*/[](){cout<<"z";}
};

/*Here the [](){code;} lambda is acting as a stand-in for void FUNC() so it  shouldn't touch anything outside of its scope*/
int LOOP = 4;
int main()
{
    if(LOOP > 2 && LOOP < 5){int THERANGEVALUE = 2; FUNC[THERANGEVALUE]();}
    FUNC[LOOP]();
    return 0;
}
```

Adding on to this, below is the solution I came up with after asking a friend. To my surprise it was actually a lot simpler than I expected. While I couldn't initialize each item in the lambda in a range easily, I could pass it into an array and set a range inside of the array instead. So while it's not quite what I was looking for, it's...good enough for my purposes. Thanks Jaime if you see this. Otherwise I'd use PilouPili's answer below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void (*FUNC[4])(void) = { //captureless lambda.
    /*ITEM_0*/        [](){ cout << "x" << endl;},
    /*ITEM_1*/        [](){cout << "y" << endl;},
    /*ITEM_2->ITEM_4*/[](){cout<<"z";},
    /*ITEM_5*/        [](){cout<<"z";}
};

int LOOP = 4;
int main()
{
    int ARR[5]={};

    for(int I = 0; I < 6;I=I+1){//handling of ranged values.
        if(I>2 && I<5){ARR[I]=2;} else {ARR[I]=I;}
    }    
    FUNC[ARR[LOOP]]();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve here. However, [`void (*FUNC[3])(void)`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28*FUNC%5B3%5D%29%28%29) is an array of 3 function pointers. From your description, I had the impression that's not what you intended. Captureless doesn't mean that lambda may not have arguments. If you want to pass the address of an array (element) to your lambda, you should make a sufficient function argument for this.

Comment: You don't have any range inside a lambda. You have 3 captureless lambdas, and none of them have any items inside, or continue anything. Are you just trying to get an array with 3 duplicate entries, and use the modulo operator to loop around it multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only see to way :
either extend your function array -> That's FUNC1 in the next example
change the value given in operator [] -> That's FUNC2 in the next example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

std::vector<void (*)(void)> init_FUNC()
{
      std::vector<void (*)(void)> func(5, [](){cout<<"z";});
      func[0]=[](){ cout << "x" << endl;};
      func[1]=[](){ cout << "y" << endl;};
      return func;
}

std::vector<void (*)(void)> FUNC1= init_FUNC();

class FUNC_MAP
{
      void (*_FUNC[3])(void) = { //captureless lambda.
    /*ITEM_0*/[](){ cout << "x" << endl;},
    /*ITEM_1*/[](){cout << "y" << endl;},
    /*ITEM_2->ITEM_4*/[](){cout<<"z";}
    };
    typedef void (*FUNC_MAP_OUT)(void);

    public:
    FUNC_MAP_OUT operator[](int i)
    {
      if(i>2 && i<5)
      {return _FUNC[2];}
      else
      {return _FUNC[i];}
    }
};


FUNC_MAP FUNC2;

/*Here the [](){code;} lambda is acting as a stand-in for void FUNC() so it  shouldn't touch anything outside of its scope*/
int LOOP = 1;
int main()
{
    FUNC1[LOOP]();
    FUNC2[LOOP]();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there anyway I could condense this?